# Whaleclub api opening a turbo position

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

Im trying to test opening a turbo position in the whaleclub api

http://docs.whaleclub.co/

and so far I have

```
wc.newTurboPosition({
direction: 'short',
market: 'BTC-USD',
type: '1min',
size: (1 * 1e8)/100 
}).then(console.log);
```

using this client library

https://github.com/askmike/whaleclub

I can open a regular position fine using

```
wc.newPosition({
direction: 'long',
market: 'BTC-USD',
leverage: 10,
size: 1 * 1e8, // 1 btc
}).then(console.log);
```

nothing shows up in my log either

so not sure why its not working for the turbo position and I tried changing the size too since the turbo market has .1 btc limit but that didnt work either. I am very new at this and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using

```
wc.newTurboPosition({
direction: 'short',
market: 'BTC-USD',
type: '5min',
size: 1 * 1e6
}).then(console.log)
```

feel kind of dumb now lol